# How to determine if it is running inside the editor or building to release, while executed by `InitializeOnLoad`?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to customize the building pipeline of a Unity project.

Some assemblies are built externally from some projects built with .NET Core SDK (targeting `netstandard2.0` and referencing the `UnityEngine.dll`), and I need to make sure these projects are recompiled after editing.

The current workaround is to use `InitializeOnLoadAttribute` to call a method that does:

1. Run `dotnet publish` command to generate the assemblies with their references.
2. Calculate the proper list of the updated `dll` and `pdb` files (compared with a hash algorithm).
3. Copy them to the Unity projects and call `AssetsDatabase.Refresh()`.

But I need to run the publish command with `Debug` configuration while in editor to debug, and with `Release` configuration to enable the optimizations and removing the `pdb` files while building to release.

How can I determine which configuration it should use inside a class with `[InitializeOnLoad]`?

Or any better way to hook the building pipeline?

Comment: you can check for the editor by checking ```Application.platform``` and check if the platform is ```RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor``` or not.

Comment: @Ankit Will building operation trigger `InitializeOnLoad`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OnPreprocessBuild to get notified before the build is started.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport.html

Comment: Then after the build, the generated assembly are still in `Release` configuration, is there another hook to restore it to `Debug` after the build?